# Lie algbra so(2n)?

Tags: lie-algebras

I am currently reading the book ``*Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations: A graduate course for physicists*'', by Jurgen Fuchs & Christoph Schweigert. On page 75 (unfortunately, the google book does not cover this page), I read:

> Another simple subalgebra of $gl(2n)$ consists of those matrices of $M$ which fulfill the relation $M^tK+KM=0$, where $K$ is the $2n\times 2n$ -matrix
>   $$K:=\begin{pmatrix}
>   0_n & 1_n \\
>   1_n & 0_n
>  \end{pmatrix}.$$

My question is how can such a definition be consistent with the normal definition of the lie algebra $so(2n)$ which consist of all $2n\times 2n$ antisymmetric matrices?

The authors also note after some sentences that

> Note that, here the symbols $sp(n)$ and $so(n)$ refer to Lie algebras over complex numbers.

I am not sure is this remark relevant to my question.

Let's take $n=1$ for example. Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
 \end{pmatrix}$,
then $M^tK+KM=0$ implies that 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & c \\
  b & d
 \end{pmatrix}\equiv M^t=-KMK^{-1}=-KMK=-\begin{pmatrix}
  d & c \\
  b & a
 \end{pmatrix}.$$
That is, $a=-d$, $c=b=0$, meaning that $M=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 \\
  0 & -a
 \end{pmatrix}$ which is inconsistent with the normal one $M=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & b \\
  -b & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Thank you very much for your remind. I will check the link.

Comment: You are right, this is confusing. But we obtain isomorphic Lie algebras, see the answer of Eric O. Korman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $\mathfrak{g}(K)$ the Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(2n)$ defined as above.
For 
$$K:=\begin{pmatrix}
  0_n & 1_n \\
  -1_n & 0_n
 \end{pmatrix}$$
we have $\mathfrak{g}(K)=\mathfrak{sp}(2n)$, the *symplectic Lie algebra*. For the orthogonal Lie algebras see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323801/two-definitions-of-the-special-orthogonal-lie-algebra), and the book of J. Humphreys, where this is explained, too. For the field we would assume algebraically closed (of characteristic zero, although it works more general).